# Physics.Simulate every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject, when player chooses force and direction there are drawn lines of movement trajectory and end position using physics.simulate. If I use it every 0.5f seconds it works well, but I have to predict trajectory and end position every frame, but then the game is lagging. How can I predict trajectory and end position every frame?

```c#
private IEnumerator destcor()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        touchhandler.listofcoll.Clear();
        touchhandler.force = (float)Math.Pow(distanceToRoller, 3);

        touchhandler.RollerMove();
        endpos = touchhandler.CheckPosition(rollerobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        destination.transform.position = endpos;
    }
}

public Vector3 CheckPosition(Rigidbody defaultRb)
{
    Physics.autoSimulation = false;
    defaultRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Vector3 defaultPos = defaultRb.position;
    Quaternion defaultRot = defaultRb.rotation;

    float timeInSec = timeCheck;

    while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {
       timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
       Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }//end while

    Vector3 futurePos = defaultRb.position;

    Physics.autoSimulation = true;

    defaultRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    defaultRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    defaultRb.transform.position = defaultPos;
    defaultRb.transform.rotation = defaultRot;

    return futurePos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

usually you should do everything related to the `Physics` engine (so also `RigidBody`) in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) or since you are using an `IEnumerator` using [`yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html) - **not** on an each frame basis.

There is a good reason why Physics Updates are not done on a per-frame basis but in fixed time intervals (therefore "FixedUpdate"): It is usually a bit time consuming and resource intense. Therefore to avoid huge lags you should avoid using the Physics every frame.

Another thing slowing you down is making repeated `GetComponent` calls. You should rather make it only once and re-use the reference later:

```c#
private RigidBody rigidBody;

private void Awake()
{
    rigidBody = rollerobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private IEnumerator destcor()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpate();

        touchhandler.listofcoll.Clear();
        touchhandler.force = (float)Math.Pow(distanceToRoller, 3);

        touchhandler.RollerMove();
        endpos = touchhandler.CheckPosition(rigidBody);
        destination.transform.position = endpos;
    }
}
```

In `CheckPosition` this line

```c#
defaultRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

makes no sense! You either already pass in a valid `RigidBody` reference or not. So overwriting it here seems to be a bit contraproductive.

If you wanted a kind of fallback here again rather store the reference once in `Awake` and later reuse it like e.g.

```c#
private RigidBody rigidBody;

private void Awake()
{
     rigidBody = rollerobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

     // now add the fallback here already
     if(!rigidBody) rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
     // or maybe you could even use
     //if(!rigidBody) rigidBody = GetComponentInChildren<RigidBody>(true);
     // in order to buble down the entire hierachy until a RigidBody is found
}
```